# how to get the correct column index for a text file using Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

**I have a text file that I want to import using pandas dataframe:**
[image]

Here is my code:

```
airfoil = pd.read_csv('NACA 8-H-12.txt',skiprows = 11,skip_blank_lines=False,header=0)
```

**However, the generated dataframe now looks like the following:**

[image]

**I cannot access any data that corresponds to a certain column. How should I separate the columns in this dataframe?**

Comment: "get to the file chopper..." ....

Comment: [pandas.read_fwf](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) ?

Comment: I think this should work so try `cols=airfoil.columns.str.split(' ')` then `out=airfoil.str.split(' ',expand=True)` finally `out.columns=cols`

Comment: ```read_fwf ``` works!